# Confidence in a rank ordering (Fez)

Tags: confidence-interval, ranking

The beautiful indie game Fez has numerous puzzles and centers around cryptic messages that are read to you in an "alien language". At one point, you can enter a village, where all the villagers speak this cryptic language:

[image: Fez village cryptic language]

I strongly believe that this "language" is just a substitution cipher for English. To crack it, I manually took some frequency statistics, based on conversations with 8 villagers:

[image: Fez letter counts]

[image: Fez letter frequency statistics]

I don't know much about rank statistics. How confident can I be that my crack will be correct? How much more would I have to take to be absolutely sure? I'm probably just going to plug in some letters and see what works, but I'm curious what the general method would be.

(also I'm sorry if these pictures are very large, I don't know how to make them smaller)

Comment: You're throwing away a great deal of information by taking away the context of the conversations themselves - for example, letter pairs, letter triples and so on contain a lot of information you can't get from individual letters. If you can distinguish the words, then you get information from word-starts and word-ends, which again are informative (e.g. "e" is more common as a word-end than a word-start. Even moreso, the conversations give you ways to check your guesses.